# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress host based routing not working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 2 service `serviceA` and `serviceB`. I setup the Ingress (Nginx) following (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/) and came up with this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-api
            port:
              number: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ui-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: example-ui
            port:
              number: 80
```

Both the Ingress only show "Schedule for sync" events:
[image]

The services are configured like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example-ui
  labels:
    app: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: example-ui
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
        service: example-ui
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: example-ui
          image: example.azurecr.io/example-ui:v1
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: ASPNETCORE_URLS
              value: http://+:80
            - name: WebApiBaseAddress
              value: http://webapi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-ui
  labels:
    app: example
    service: example-ui
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer #Tested with ClusterIP as well
  ports:
    - appProtocol: http
      name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    service: example-ui
```

The services are available when I configure them with LoadBalanacer and the logs look ok. When I try to reach any of the services, it fails. I use Azure FrontDoor configured with the Origins and also tried to call using Postman settings the Host Header. Unfortunately, all I get is this:

[image]

For me, it looks like Ingress is not routing correctly. The Ingress Controller also shows no sign of activity in case of a request.

[image]

What could be the reason that the request doesn't reach the service when using Ingress? Is there any better way to trace the request to see where it gets lost?

Comment: Have you tried `type: NodePort` in the `example-ui` service declaration? Using type `type: Loadbalancer` would make a separately routed loadbalancer in your cloud provider. However you already have a Loadbalancer abstracted by the `kind: Ingress` declaration which you want to "attach" services to. `NodePort` is necessary because it creates a port routable from outside your VM where your nginx loadbalancer can find it.

Comment: I did not try this yet as the documentation only states `ClusterIP` but I did now. Unfortunately, this also does not help. The services are still not reachable.

Comment: Please try this and update the status